# Как преобразовать mp4 в blob протокол?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Многие видели, что у кинотеатрах файл видео выводится в blob протоколе, но так же у некоторых кинотеатрах вообще не отправляется заголовок apple/m3u8. То есть, невозможно получить ссылку. Так вот, у меня есть видео в mp4 (ссылки) как мне их правильно выводить в плеер в blob протоколе и без возможности отправки заголовок?

Если есть видео где кто-то это делает в react, тогда можете пожалуйста его скинуть. Как кошку втыкнуть в него :D